# How to identify appropriate implementation of UML Association Classes?

Tags: associations, uml, class-diagram

I was reading through a tutorial on UML Class diagrams and I'm having problems understanding Association Classes and why this `MileageCredit` class isn't part of the `FrequentFlyer` class in the below example (taken from figure 11 of the tutorial [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/index.html)):

[image]

Assuming that it's a one-to-one relation between FrequentFlyer and MileageCredit (if a person had two FrequentFlyer memberships they'd still have different frequentFlyerNumber numbers) then I would just put these `baseMiles` and `bonusMiles` properties in the <kbd>FrequentFlyer</kbd> Class itself.

Could someone please explain why this is wrong?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the use case. Please modify your topic accordingly.

Comment: Thanks - hope title is clear now

Comment: Yep, now it's much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MileageCredit is an AssociationClass, which means this is simultaneously an Association (linking) Flight and FrequentFlyer) and a class that describes this Association. This fact is depicted by a dashed line connecting the class and the association. Note that acording to the UML specification those class and association together create one entity.

In your example there is Association (that is called MileageCredit) between FrequentFlyer and a Flight. You may assume that this shows a Flight taken by a FrequentFlyer. As for these Association you need additional information (number of award and bonus miles that are awarded to the FrequentFlyer for this Flight) this association has this extra Class describing this information.

If you created baseMiles and bonusMiles on FrequentFlyer that would have absolutely no relationship to the Association - it would be only information about total points awarded to the FrequentFlyer.

Comment: Note also that on code level MileageCredit will probably become either a class owned by FrequentFlyer  with association to Flight or a separate class with associations to both Flight and FrequentFlyer.

Comment: Thanks - I think that's been my confusion of mixing it up with a  database schema

Comment: One can think of an association class siting between (usually) two classes and linking them with 1-m*n-1 relation (the * is the assoc-class).